# How do I save color mapped array of same dimensions of the original array?

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I have data that I would like to save as png's. I need to keep the exact pixel dimensions - I don't want any inter-pixel interpolation, smoothing, or up/down sizing, etc. I do want to use a colormap, though (and mayber some other features of `matplotlib`'s `imshow`). As I see it there are a couple ways I could do this:

1) Manually roll my own colormapping. (I'd rather not do this)

2) Figure out how to make sure the pixel dimenensions of the image in the figure produced by imshow are exactly correct, and then extract just the image portion of the figure for saving.

3) Use some other method which will directly give me a color mapped array (i.e. my NxN grayscale array -> NxNx3 array, using one of matplotlibs colormaps). Then save it using another png save method such as `scipy.misc.imsave`.

**How can I do one of the above?** (Or another alternate)

My problem arose when I was just saving the figure directly using `savefig`, and realized that I couldn't zoom into details. Upscaling wouldn't solve the problem, since the blurring between pixels is exactly one of the things I'm looking for - and the pixel size has a physical meaning.

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-50.0,50,.1), np.arange(-50.0,50,.1))
Z = np.abs(np.sin(2*np.pi*(X**2+Y**2)**.5))/(1+(X/20)**2+(Y/20)**2)
plt.imshow(Z,cmap='inferno', interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig('colormapeg.png')
plt.show()
```

Note zooming in on the interactive figure gives you a very different view then trying to zoom in on the saved figure. I could up the resolution of the saved figure - but that has it's own problems. I really just need the resolution fixed.

Comment: Try `plt.savefig('colormapeg.png', dpi=1000)`?

Comment: That still doesn't work very well because it up-samples. If you upsample it enough so there's say 10+ pixels per pixel in the original image, it partly works (visually, at least) because of the nearest neighbor interpolation. The thing I'm interested in here is examining details on the scale of a pixel - and exactly how pixelation affects that - so anything that messes with the pixelation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [`plt.imsave()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html).

In this case,

```
plt.imsave("filename.png", Z, cmap='inferno')
```

Comment: Oh. There's a function directly for that. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks!